# Series combination of RL and RC circuits(AC Analysis)

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, voltage-divider, current-divider

While studying for my end-term exam through past year papers(of my college). I came across this question in which we need to do AC Analysis.

> Need to find out the values of Resistor (R) and Capacitor (C), also the phase angle between Vs and Vb, as well as Vb and I.

Info given:

- |Va|related to|Vb|
- Phase difference ∠Vb -∠Va

I did try researching on the Internet but I do not have the correct keywords I guess. Couldn't even find anything here on EE.SE either.(Internet links as answer would be most appreciated)

### My Attempt

After converting to phasors(omega=100π rad/s),the first thing I can think of is to use Voltage Division Rule as Vs is given[in terms of 240sin(100πt)] then equate according to |Va| =|Vb|/3--but I get an equation in 2 variables(R and C).

How do I use the phase difference given?
I can easily find other phase differences once I figure out R and C.

Edit: The exact Question is uploaded on [Chegg](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/q1-circuit-shown-following-figure-find-values-resistor-r-capacitor-c-val-v6-3-phase-differ-q78918906)--sadly I don't have a Chegg account.

Comment: If 90 deg then impedances must form a right angle triangle.

Comment: What do you know about the current through each element? What does that tell you about the relative impedances and their angles? We don't hand out homework solutions here; we expect you to do a fair amount of work.

Comment: It's not exactly homework but okay. (1) V = iZ (Thanks) ; (2) I'm still trying to figure out wdym.

Comment: It's the other way around. Using phase difference, you have to get the second equation. Two unknown variables, two equations..solve..

Comment: Just try making the RC impedance 90 degrees out of phase with the LC impedance and the adjust to get the right magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

Let \$Z_{LR}\$ and \$Z_{RC}\$ be the impedances. Then

$$
V_b = \frac{Z_{LR}}{Z_{LR}+Z_{RC}}V_{in} \quad\text{and}\quad V_a = \frac{Z_{RC}}{Z_{LR}+Z_{RC}}V_{in}
$$
so
$$
\frac{V_b}{V_a} = \frac{Z_{LR}}{Z_{RC}} = 3i
$$
(or maybe it's \$-3i\$.) Now just solve for \$Z_{RC}\$.

Comment: Thank you my good sir. I was actually trying to figure out what you said in your comment for the past 20 mins. Btw, here LC refers to RL I believe and i is iota(usually represented by 'j' in EE)

Comment: You're right about LC vs. LR -- I'll change it!